# Disposing mail files from code behind

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, outlook-2010

I have a `vb.net` win-form application.

When user select and click on a button, I am opening `.msg` file and it works fine.

But if same file is selected and try to open it again, I get the file access error message.

***"Cannot open file filename. File may not exits,you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program."***

I have tried both the these codes below, but the end result is same

```
Dim Proc As New Process
Dim ProcInfo As New ProcessStartInfo

ProcInfo.FileName = "FilePath"
ProcInfo.UseShellExecute = True
Proc.StartInfo = ProcInfo
Proc.Start()
Proc.Dispose()
```

And

```
Process.Start("FilePath")
```

As I know, using `Process.Start()` we don't need to dispose manually.

Any idea what cause this issue

It seems even if we close the outlook dialog, it doesn't release the .msg file.